# Driver path incorrect? What Am I doing wrong

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium with java to test a login form and I get this error any ideas?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.selenium.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

This is my code:

```
package com.selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //Cambia la ruta del teu directori perque funcioni//
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Sethei\\Desktop\\M05_Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");

        //Test login
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("12345678");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Comment: If you are trying to instantiate chrome, why not use a chrome driver? gecko target Mozilla especially and you can try new FirefoxDriver();